# I am Suddenly getting Play-Service-app-indexing:10.0.1 error in gradle of android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1

Here is my build.gradle file of my project in Android Studio, the errors has came suddenly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pandey.nidhiiot"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apk 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1-beta1'
// Glide image library
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'

   }

apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try compile in place of apk

Comment: and you need to compile those dependencies which you want. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.0' this is different dependencies

Comment: Not resolved Error has jst bcame almost sam from 10.0.1 to 10.0.0 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40732638/4625829), you should remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

since using the new library dependency (below) should be enough.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
```

I copied the part of your gradle file for dependencies and encountered the same. After removing the duplicate (`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`) and replacing the dependency as mentioned above, the build was successful.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apk 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1-beta1'
    // Glide image library
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Check if just one of them is necessary. 
Also check changing firebase-appindexing to 10.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be helpful

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
 defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.example.pandey.nidhiiot"
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 25
 versionCode 1
 versionName "1.0"
 multiDexEnabled true
 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
 release {
     minifyEnabled false
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
  }
 }

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Glide image library
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


   }

apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```