# All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle

## Images

---

[image: Android Studio report]

---

[image: No 10.2.0 library available]

---

## Exception

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions `9.8.0`, `10.2.0`. Examples include `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0`

I am mixing versions `9.8.0` and `10.2.0`.

## Lastest versions

- *com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness*: `10.2.0`
- *com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing*: `9.8.0`

## Issue

I must use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.0` because it includes that latest update that I need.

However, there is no `10.2.0` version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing`, `9.8.0` is the latest one.

## Question

So, I can't downgrade *fitness* because I need the latest version, but there is no version for *appindexing* that matches it.

What do I do in this case?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732418/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-appindexing10-0-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Indexing moved to the Firebase bundle.  A lot is moving there and if you don't use Firebase I'd recommend migrating & checking it out.  It certainly seems to be the future of where this is all heading.

More info on how to migrate the AppIndexing element can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/migrate)

Comment: That made it, thanks. Could elaborate more on Firebase?

Comment: It's where Google seems to be putting all their mobile efforts so I can see more going into it.  Just take a look at https://firebase.google.com