# Firebase Authentication Library does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the official sample source code of Google Firebase Authentication for my project. The problem seems simple, but it is not actually.

I have declared the dependency on Gradle file as shown below:

```
// Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

The following imports are not configured as expected:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
```

If I will hover over the import, then says Add library `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3` to classpath.

app Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    // compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sampletest.app.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')

    // implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // Firebase Core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    // Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    // Ads
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    // Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'
    // App Indexing
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    // Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    // Cloud Functions
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'
    // Cloud Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    // Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    // Crash Reporting
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.0'
    // Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    // Dynamic Links
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.1'
    // Invites
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.3'
    // In-App Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:17.0.1'
    // In-App Messaging Display
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1'
    // ML Kit: Model Interpreter
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.0'
    // ML Kit: Vision
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.0'
    // ML Kit: Image Labeling
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:15.0.0'
    // Performance Monitoring
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    // Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    // Remote Config
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    // Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    // Facebook Android SDK (only required for Facebook Login)
    // Used in FacebookLoginActivity.
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

    // Twitter Android SDK (only required for Twitter Login)
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add google plugin in

Comment: Please paste your Build.gradle too. However, did you try clean-rebuild project?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi I have added google plugin actually.

Comment: @Mohsen I have tried multiple times to clean and rebuild the project. I have also tried to invalidate caches and restart android studio, but it does not work.

Comment: then add   repositories { maven() google() }

Comment: @JonathanWilliams Please add your Build.gradle then.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi I have added also maven { url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository }

Comment: add google() as well and do add google first and then maven()

Comment: @Mohsen there are multiple build.gradle files because the project is implemented with instant play.

Comment: show us your app level `buld.gradle` file

Comment: @JonathanWilliams try my answer

Comment: You need to be consistent with the versions of firebase library you are using. If you are using 16.0.3, then most other libraries should also be that version. Sometimes these problems arise because you are using different versions of the libraries that are not quite compatible. Check Here for a solution to a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203210/firebase-error-cannot-access-zzanb-after-using-play-services-xxx9-8-00/41063447#41063447

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the implemented version from

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Comment: whats the logic in change version number 3 to 4 ?

Comment: This is the officially available library for Firebase authertication. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

Comment: I got a different problem with using 16.0.3 that says 'The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1.', but yeah changing to 16.0.4 solves the problem

Comment: @HankChan Please share your Gradle file.

Comment: so you mean to say `16.0.3` was not official library for Firebase authertication?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Go to Tools -->  Firebase --> Then Assistant window Comes up Follow Guideline for firebase authentication.

or Follow Guidelines From Here:

[Google Firebase Authentication Steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 0):

in you project gradle  add

```
  buildscript {

repositories {
    google() // Google's Maven repository
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

in your's `Build.Gradle (App Module)` project App  gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this logic to the android project, but it still does not work. I am thinking if Java build path or any cache remains the problem.

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin 
see this 4.1.0  change it to 4.0.1

Comment: and replace repositories with mine repositories ...and dnt change their alignment

Comment: yes, but the problem is remaining. I will get error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseAuth. I can not understand why the project is not compiled properly.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project and sync gradle

Comment: Check again my update that still does not work. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181207/discussion-between-jonathan-williams-and-atif-abbasi).